# Swift IOS Failed to access json array data using Codable

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, codable

How to access JSON using Codable. this is my sample json.

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "Data received successfully",
    "course": {
        "id": 1,
        "description": "something",
        "name": "ielts",
        "attachments": [
            {
                "id": 809,
                "attachment": "https:--",
                "file_name": "syllabus.pdf",
                "description": "course",

            },
            {
                "id": 809,
                "attachment": "https:--",
                "file_name": "syllabus.pdf",
                "description": "course",
            }]
        "upcased_name": "IELTS"
     }
}
```

This is my code.

```
struct ResponseObject: Codable {
    let course: [Course]
}

struct Course: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let description: String
    let attachments: [Attachments]
}

struct Attachments: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let attachment: String
    let file_name: String
    let description: String
    let about: String
}

var course: [Course] = []
```

This is my api call.

```
func fetchUserData() {

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Authorization": "Token token="+UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "auth_token")!,
        "Accept": "application/json"
    ]
    let params = ["course_id" : "1"] as [String : AnyObject]
    self.showSpinner("Loading...", "Please wait!!")
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        AF.request(SMAConstants.courses_get_course_details , parameters: params, headers:headers ).responseDecodable(of: ResponseObject.self, decoder: self.decoder) { response in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.hideSpinner()
                guard let value = response.value else {
                    print(response.error ?? "Unknown error")
                    return
                }

                self.course = value.course
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I am getting following error.

> responseSerializationFailed(reason:
>   Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.decodingFailed(error:
>   Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Array,
>   Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue:
>   "course", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode
>   Array but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))))

Comment: Please **read** the error message. The value of `course` is not an array, it's a dictionary (single object). And there is no `about` key in `Attachment`

Comment: You should test smaller pieces of your code; for instance, here you are discovering your Codable stuff is broken when you do the API call. It would be very helpful to if instead, for instance, you included some test JSON in your project and then decoded that by loading it from the bundle, then once you are sure that works move on to the API call.

Answer (score 2):

Your model object does not match the JSON structure. Try this instead:

```
struct ResponseObject: Codable {
    let status, message: String
    let course: Course
}

struct Course: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let courseDescription, name: String
    let attachments: [Attachment]
    let upcasedName: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case courseDescription = "description"
        case name, attachments
        case upcasedName = "upcased_name"
    }
}

struct Attachment: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let attachment, fileName, attachmentDescription: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, attachment
        case fileName = "file_name"
        case attachmentDescription = "description"
    }
}
```

and to download and parse this with plain Swift and Foundation, use code like this:

```
let url = URL(string: SMAConstants.courses_get_course_details)!
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    if let error = error {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    if let data = data {
      do {
        let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseObject.self, from: data)
        // access your data here
      } catch {
         print(error)
      }
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: I tried I am getting this error. responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.decodingFailed(error: Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "file_name", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "course", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "attachments", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"file_name\", intValue: nil) (\"file_name\").", underlyingError: nil))))

Comment: The error message is very precise: you have a course attachment that does not contain a "file_name". Make the `fileName` property optional to deal with this situation.

Comment: can you tell me how to use these values in Alamofire request.

Comment: I am to trying to return attachments.count but its not working , and how to use it to tableview cell.

Comment: Getting the count should be as easy as `responseObject.course.attachments.count`. I would also recommend not using a massive library like Alamofire for this when just a few lines of plain Swift code and Foundation tools will do the job just fine. Getting data into tableviews is an entirely different matter and should be asked in a separate question, once you've worked through one of the many and readily available tutorials and questions here.

Comment: responseObject.course.attachments.count not giving data

Comment: hi I am waiting for your reply.